# sonar qube begin task failing - Unexpected exit code received from batch file: -532462766

Tags: sonarqube

I m getting below error while starting sonar analysis in tfs build task.
Please Help !

```
*************************************************************************

Starting task: Fetch the Quality Profile from SonarQube

****************************************************************************** 
Executing the powershell script: 

D:\kannappan_sonar\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.35\SonarQubePreBuild.ps1 SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 1.1 
Default properties file was found at D:\kannappan_sonar\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.35\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.1\SonarQube.Analysis.xml 
Loading analysis properties from D:\kannappan_sonar\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.35\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.1\SonarQube.Analysis.xml 
Pre-processing started. 
Preparing working directories... 
Checking for updates...

Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
    at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.WebClientDownloader.Download(String url)
    at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.SonarWebService.GetProperties(String projectKey, String projectBranch)
    at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.FetchArgumentsAndRulesets(ISonarQubeServer server, ProcessedArgs args, TeamBuildSettings settings, IDictionary`2& serverSettings, List`1& analyzersSettings)
    at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.DoExecute(ProcessedArgs args)
    at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.Execute(String[] args)
    at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.Program.Main(String[] args) SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild Begin Step 2.2 18:11:45.209  Loading analysis properties from D:\kannappan_sonar\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.35\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.1\SonarQube.Analysis.xml 18:11:45.271  Updating build integration targets... 18:11:45.286  Fetching analysis configuration settings... Pre-processing succeeded.
    Unexpected exit code received from batch file: -532462766
```

Answer (score 1):

The crux of this error is: `The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized`

It is likely that you're trying to analyze a project on which the permissions have been restricted. In both the begin and end steps, you'll need to pass an [analysis token](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token) from an account with permissions to analyze the project.

Comment: After giving  execute permission in project @sonar dashboard , even password worked in my case. Dint use token